# filter the listed items according to their Categories in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

i have been suffering to get the items' data listed according to their categories

i don't know what am I doing wrong.

so basically, I have data coming from a bearer token API and it is listed successfully on the screen but I want as a second step to list according to their categories. there are five categories and more than 60 items.

here is my code:

```
  const [filterList, setFilterList] = useState("all");
  const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState(products);

  // filtering data by category

  useEffect(() => {
    let isValidScope = true;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      // pass filterList in fetch to get products for the selected category ??
      // pass parameters to fetch accordingly

      const res = await fetch(
        "https://myapi-api.herokuapp.com/api/categories/",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      if (!isValidScope) {
        return;
      }

         setNewProduct(res);
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      isValidScope = false;
    };
  }, [filterList]);



function onFilterValueSelected(filterValue) {
    setFilterList(filterValue);
  }
  let filteredProductList = newProduct?.filter((product) => {
    // should return true or false

    // option 2 if product has a category property
    return product.category === filterList;
    // existing code
    if (filterList === "electronics") {
      return product.electronics == true;
    } else if (filterList === "clothing") {
      return product.clothing === true;
    } else if (filterList === "accsessories") {
      return product.accsessories === true;
    } else if (filterList === "furniture") {
      return product.furniture === true;
    } else if (filterList === "hobby") {
      return product.hobby === true;
    } else {
      // here dont return truthy
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Any chance to let us know what is the structure of `product`? Also how filters might be selected, Is it possible to select more than one?

Comment: the structure of a `product` is `name`, `price`, `avatar` and `description`.

Comment: no its supposed not to select one product for multiple categories, however it could be more than one product for each category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch all of them once when the component mounts and them filter them on every render based on the selected filter instead of fetching products everytime in useEffect when filter changes.

```
const [filterCategory, setFilterCategory] = useState("");
   
function onFilterValueSelected(filterValue) {
    setFilterCategory(filterValue);
  }

  let filteredProductList = newProduct?.filter((product) => {
    return product.category === filterCategory;     
  });
```

Comment: im getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: newProduct.filter is not a function`

Comment: filter functions works on arrays. Are your fetched products returned and stored in an array? You call setNewProduct with (res) and I didn't change that since i dont know the response format you get. You  can try it first with hardcoded products to see that it works

Comment: Also you initialize the newProduct state with "products" which I dont know where it comes from and what is inside so I didnt touch that as well.

Comment: Oh I think I fugured out what happened. The useEffect you use its to fetch product categories and not products, right? If so, remove useEffect completely

Comment: well i guess that i need to fetch the data with a new API which only for categories

Comment: the data is coming as follows `{
    "message": "Success",
    "categories": [
        {
            "_id": `

Comment: so i guess it supposed to be an array like this: `const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState([]);` but even with this way it gives me same error `newProduct.filter is not a function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249775/discussion-between-marios-and-hazal-kaya).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
const categories = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'] // Since you hardcode it anyway, its fine to have a hardcoded array here. But you can retrieve unique categories by getting Object.values on category and new Set() them
return (<> {categories.forEach(category => {
fetchedData.filter(el => el.category === category).map(filteredElement => {return <h1> {filteredElement.property} <h1>})}) </>}
```